# How have Schumann resonances varied in previous eras and periods on Earth?

Tags: earth-history, electromagnetism

Schumann resonances vary with losses in the cavity between Earth and the ionosphere and variability of the upper boundary due to atmospheric conductivity and ionospheric dynamics:

> BALSER, M., WAGNER, C.
> Observations of Earth–Ionosphere Cavity Resonances.
> Nature 188, 638–641 (1960).
> https://doi.org/10.1038/188638a0

Especially during warmer and thus wetter periods the Schumann resonances might have been lower due to increased atmospheric conductivity.

What different values have the Schumann resonances had in Earths history?